# create a list in models.py in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

So i was trying to create a quiz app where i wish to store the questions that my user has attempted which i was trying was associated with the user class.

So i have two classes currently in my models.py file: class questions which contains a charfield for question, an integerfield for answer,and 4 charfields for choices named accordingly;

and the second class is basically just a user class having fields to save the name,email,username and password of the user.

now what i was trying was is there any method to store the questions using the questionid in an array/list/set/dict associated with the user .

Comment: I guess the relationship between users and questions is many-to-many. If you want to reach the users of questions and the questions of users in an easy way, just add ManyToManyField for user or question model. You can check docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You could either accomplish your goal with database relationships: Please refer to Django Doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Or you could create another Model 'Choices' with Fields:

- user_id
- question_id
- answer_number

This approach would be a bit redundant, but it'd work. You would save every answer your user sends as a new Choice-Entry.